# Keras model window sliding prediction using filters

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to load a Keras model using saved training weights and make prediction on RBG images.

My model generate a binary value for each pixel. For the input, the model should load `w x w` pixels around the center pixel, then apply a an special filter (e.g. crop the window circularly and rotate the circle. just assume some filter that uses all pixel in that patch) and then make the prediction.

```
# Circular filter added to each window
def circular_mask(width = 5):
    radius = (width - 1) / 2
    Y, X = np.ogrid[:width, :width]
    distance = np.sqrt((Y - radius) ** 2 + (X - radius) ** 2)
    return distance <= radius
```

I can prepare the dataset myself, generate a huge numpy array and call `model.predict()` on that huge matrix. But when the image is large, the data doesn't fit in the GPU's memory. My questions is, is there a better way to automate the sliding window prediction on the image on which my `special_filter` is added to every window?

Comment: I am not sure how it this circular masking works, but couldn't you just split your array into batches and use ``predict`` or ``predict_on_batch``?

Comment: @FallenApart Yes, from your prespective this filter is not important. Let’s say for every pixel, I want to capture 33 by 33 pixels around, apply my filter and then send it to model for predictions